# How to get the value type

Tags: xslt, xpath

Teach me Please.

Is there a way to get the type of the variable you specify?
For example, I'm thinking about the use of getting a type and outputting it to a message, or comparing types to make a condition as follows.

Or is it possible to do it?

```xsl
<!-- example -->
<xsl:message select="[get_type_function]([any_variable_as_string])" />

<!-- message -->
xs:string
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect **the type** of a variable to be, if a declare `<xsl:variable name="var1" as="item()*" select="1"/>`, is the type you want then the declared `item()*` or is it `xs:integer` or `xs:integer*`? In the context of XSLT 1 and EXSLT there is http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/object-type/index.html to get the rudimentary types `'string', 'number', 'boolean', 'node-set', 'RTF' or 'external'`, but XSLT/XPath 1 have a rather simple type system and don't declare types anyway, in XSLT/XPath 2 or 3 the type system is much more complex.

In the context of Saxon 9 EE or PE there is http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/type.html so for the above sample

```
    <xsl:variable name="var1" as="item()*" select="1"/>
    <xsl:message select="saxon:type($var1)('name')" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/>
    <xsl:variable name="var2" as="item()*" select="'foo'"/>
    <xsl:message select="saxon:type($var2)('name')" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/>
```

you get

```
integer
string
```

but I am not sure how you would get a fitting type for a heterogeneous sequence as

```
    <xsl:variable name="var3" as="item()*" select="1, 'foo'"/>
    <xsl:message select="saxon:type($var3)('name')" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/>
```

also simply gives integer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I confirmed to get the type of integer and string. If the contents of the variable is element or attribute, is there a way to get that the type?

Comment: You can for sure (in XPath and XSLT 2 or newer) test for certain sequence types https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-sequencetype-syntaxe.g. `$var instance of attribute()` or `$var instance of element()` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-instance-of so you can kind of implement your own function to return the type of a certain set of types by checking for all of them with `if` expressions in XPath or `xsl:choose` in XSLT.

Comment: I confirmed that I can check the type with instance of. Thank you for teaching me.